# Error "option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 12" in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Recently I Installed Xamarin in My Visual Studio 2017. And I Have Lots Of Problems For Installing It. Now All Of My Problems Fixed With Searching On Google Except This. The VS Code Gives Me This Error When I Want To Build My App:

```
option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 12
```

How Can I Fix It?

This Is My [Project](http://yekupload.ir/005ea09906a378cd/App1.rar) Link

Comment: You can try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder, then re-build your project, if you still have issue? If you still get this issue, you could upload your project, I can test it for you.

Comment: Thats My First Project. I Didnt Write Anything. But Anyway I Will Upload It. Thank You.

Comment: Ok, waitting for yuor update.

Comment: I test it in my VS 2017, my version number is 4.7.03190, I can run it normally, Please check the android setting like this url https://imgur.com/a/yWRaRXw

Comment: I Think Its Installation Problem But I Don't Know What Problem. As You Said It Works In Your VS Code But My Code Does Not Compile.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in VS Professional 2015. I have already reinstalled the entire software but no luck. Still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

It seems, this issue comes with latest version of JDK only. Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 is compatible till JDK 8. Try downgrading your JDK. I could fix it this way.

Similar discussion you can find here:
https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/52/52178/bug.html